# Why is the "main" form unresponsive when i am using async/await to Login?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 public class Administration
{
    public static async Task<bool> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var context = new EmployeeManagementEntities();
        var user = await Task.Run(() => context.Users.Where(t => t.Username == username && t.Password == password && t.Status == (int)Status.Active).FirstOrDefault());

        if (user != null)
        {
            frmMain.CurrentUser = user;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AreValid())
        {
            if (await Administration.Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                var main = new frmMain();
                this.Hide();
                main.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                lblUP.Visible = true;
            }
            errorProvider1.Clear();
        }
    }
```

I want to make the Loginform responsive when i press login,After i press login the form becomes responsive but as soon as the main from loads it becomes unresponsve for a few minutes.

The **Administration** class is created in a class folder in solution explorer and i am calling it in the **Form** class since it is static.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: If the *Main* form becomes unresponsive, you should post *Main's* code, not the login form's.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use a thread pool thread just to listen to the database query, EF has built-in async selectors for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var user = await context.Users.Where(t => t.Username == username && t.Password == password && t.Status == (int)Status.Active).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about your solution, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer